# Does Windows Server 2012 R2 OEM require different install media?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I want to install an instance of Windows Server 2012 R2 OEM as a virtual machine on our VM server.

Does the OEM version require me to download a different OS image that so we can install and use the OS?

Comment: I touched up your question to make it less of a licensing issue, but do be aware that an OEM license is non transferable, which has some problematic implications for virtualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the quick test I did, an OEM product key will not work on a standard ISO that you can download from Microsoft.

I got the below error trying to activate it, which I suppose makes sense.  The OEM Product ID on an OEM version of Windows is different from a non-OEM version, and ends in `AAOEM` to make the distinction clear.

[image]

[OEM licenses also come with a number of restrictions that are increasingly onerous with as virtualization and more complex IT infrastructures become increasingly common](http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2013/04/30/windows-server-oem-licensing-is-cheaper-but-not-always.aspx).

Comment: I think I found the answer after reading about 15 articles. Basically OEM is tied to the motherboard of the physical machine and can be virtualized but can only stay on that machine and not transferred. I created an ISO image from the original disc and will use that to install the VMs.